# Can we generate C code for matlab function having "set_param " to update tunable parameters of masked simulink block?

Tags: matlab, embedded, simulink

I want to generate C code for a simulink model for TMSF2812 target processor using MATLAB R2010a and CCS V3.3. The model include a masked block having tunable parameters,which I need to update based on some criteria in simulations as well as on target processor in real time.For simulations I have wrote a matlab function which use "set_param", which can update parameters on run time.
Now my question can we generate C code for matlab function (set_param) and whether it will also update the tunable parameters on target processor? If the idea is wrong , plz suggest me some easy way.

Note: The tunable parameters of the masked block cannot be configured as block inputs, we need to update them as tunable parameters.

Thanks 
Khan

Comment: You cannot generate code for set_param (or any other functions not part of the Embedded MATLAB subset).  However, if you haven't Inlined Parameters, then the mask parameters should be part of a tunable parameters structure (in the C code generated by Simulink Coder) and hence can be changed from within the C-Code.

Comment: Thank you Phil! My model contains fuzzy system to update the parameter of the masked. So is there any method so that I can update the parameter in simulink level and that also work when I generate code? What I mean is that in the generated code fuzzy system should update the same parameters . plz suggest me an easy way, Thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to do the same thing in the generated code as in simulation (using set_param). Are you absolutely certain that the block can't be modified to change the parameters to be signals?

Comment: Phil! I have no experience in changing the parameters to signals. The  tune able  parameters of the masked block are input arguments of a function written as .m file. So is it possible to change the tunable parameters of masked block (input arguments of a function, .m ) as input signals of that masked block? If yes please help me in this regard. Thanks once again

Comment: The masked simulink block is nid( represents fractional order derivative or integral) which is using the following function taken from open  source(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8312-ninteger/content/ninteger/nid.m)

Comment: You aren't going to be able to use Simulink Coder to generate C-code for the function in the above link.

Comment: So how I should solve this problem . Sir , please give me some useful directions.

Comment: You need to spent time studying and understanding the limitations of Simulink Coder.  Some useful places to start are http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html, and http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html

Comment: Like Phil said, consider changing your parameters to signals. This blog explains the difference: http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2011/03/08/how-do-i-change-a-block-parameter-based-on-the-output-of-another-block/

Comment: Thanks pmb!If I change parameters to signal etc , then can I use the masked block for generating C code for my application and target TMS 320F2812?